# How to prevent rstrip('.0') from removing 0 before decimal in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
fileA = fileA.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip('.0')).fillna('')
```

Output - is eliminating 0 before decimal as well, which shouldnt happen,
As there are column with numbers(Serial no.) and other with names ,want to make concatenate of all column, I have tried converting to string and make concat of all but float is converting to string ,I have to code above to remove trailing zero but it is also removing 0 by default before .deccimal point which is making data different from original.

Please help to convert `0.0` as `0` and `number.0` as `''` where number is 1 to 9 in python

Try to code in one liner as the file is huge and this code is game changer for entire file

Comment: Why do you want to convert `number.0` to `''` rather than `number`?

Comment: If you just want to remove `.0` at the end, use a regexp `.str.replace(r'\.0$', '')`

Comment: You can’t prevent .rstrip() from doing what it is documented to do. It is the wrong function for the job.  Later versions of Python have .removesuffix().

Comment: Can you say a bit more about *"make concatenate of all column"*? Do you want to export into some kind of delimited text file? In that case you could use `fileA.to_csv()` or similar - you can choose whichever delimiter you prefer.